# Javascript is not working after adding some functions

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, events

I was working on project which required to change background color of webpage when user hover mouse on a textfield and whole webpage theme must change when mouse pointer is on that textfield. It worked well but when I added a submit button and made a function to change its properties on mouse over and on mouse out, whole Javascript code stopped working!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php
    function redirect($url){
        ob_start();
        header('Location: '.$url);
        ob_end_flush();
        die();
    }
    $error = "";
    $myurl = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    if (isset($_GET['name'])) {
    $name = $_GET['name'];
    } else {
        $name = "";
    }
    //$name = $_GET["name1"];
    $name = trim($name);
    if(empty($name)){
        $error="";
    }else{
        echo $myurl;
    }
?>
<html>
<head>
    <title>We Wish</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins&display=swap');
        @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Comfortaa:700&display=swap');
        body{
            background-color: #1a1a1a;
        }
        input{
            background-color: transparent;
            border-radius: 50px;
            border: 1.5px solid white;
        }
        #pallete{
            position: absolute;
            left: 50%;
            top: 50%;
            transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
        }
        #nametf{
            width: 200px;
            height: 20px;
            padding: 5px 10px;
            color: white;
            font-size: 15px;
            font-family: 'Comfortaa', cursive;
        }
        #nametf:hover{
            border: 1.5px solid #1a1a1a;
        }
        #btn{
            color: white;
            font-family: 'Comfortaa', cursive;
            background-color: transparent;
            border: 1.5px solid white;
            border-radius: 50px;
            padding: 9px 20px 8px 20px;
            margin-top: 15px;
            text-align: center;
            text-decoration: none;
            display: inline-block;
            font-size: 10px;
            cursor: pointer;
            transition-duration: 0s;
        }
        #btn:hover{
            color: #1a1a1a;
            background-color: cyan;
            border-color: cyan;
            box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px cyan;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <center>
        <div id="pallete">
            <form method="get" action="wwhome.php">
                <input type="text" name="name1" id="nametf" onmouseover="bgChange('white','#1a1a1a')" onmouseout="bgChange('#1a1a1a','white')" onchange="widen()" value="" required>
            </form>
            <span>
                <input type="submit" name="submit" id="btn" value="CREATE" onmouseover="glow('on')" onmouseout="glow('off')">
            </span>
        </div>
    </center>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var nametf = document.getElementById('nametf');
    function bgChange(bg,color){
        document.body.style.background = bg;
        nametf.style.color = color;
        var btn = document.getElementById('btn');
        if(bg=='white'){
            //btn.style.transition-duration = "0s";
            btn.style.border = "1.5px solid #1a1a1a";
            btn.style.color = "#1a1a1a";
        } else {
            //btn.style.transition-duration = "0s";
            btn.style.border = "1.5px solid white";
            btn.style.color = "white";
        }
    }
    function widen(){
        var value = nametf.value;
        if(value.length > 17){
            nametf.style.width = '300px';
        } else {
            nametf.style.width = '200px';
        }
    }
    function glow(mode){
        if(mode=='on'){
            btn.style.transition-duration = "0.4s";
            btn.style.color = "#1a1a1a";
            btn.style.background-color = "cyan";
            btn.style.border-color = "cyan";
            btn.style.box-shadow = "0px 0px 15px cyan";
        } else {
            btn.style.transition-duration = "0.4s";
            btn.style.color = "white";
            btn.style.background-color = "transparent";
            btn.style.border-color = "white";
            btn.style.box-shadow = "0px 0px 0px transparent";
        }
    }
</script>
</html>
```

I even tried alerting a message without any function but still it didn't work!!

Comment: Do you have any error in your JS console ? (F12)

Comment: What didn't work? Are you getting any errors in the dev tools console?

Comment: `btn.style.transition-duration` is going to be the first place where you're getting issues. you can't have a dash in a property name just bare like that. Try changing those properties with dashes in them in another way

Comment: It was changing bg color when I hovered mouse on textfield (That is included in bgChange function) but after adding glow function, even the bgChange function stopped working! It's like javascript code has no effect!

Comment: Rather than applying each style with `btn.style = ...`, you may have an easier time managing styles using `document.body.classList.add('text-hovered')`, and then in your CSS you can add rulesets like `body.text-hovered #btn { border-color: white; ... }`.

Comment: JavaScript uses "camel case" for CSS properties. `btn.style.backgroundColor`, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`btn.style.transition-duration` is going to be the first place where you're getting issues. you can't have a dash in a property name just bare like that. Try changing those properties with dashes in them in another way

`btn.style['transition-duration']` may work, I'm not 100% sure, but I am sure that the dashes are creating basically a syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning values to property that has hyphen in them ( `-` ). In Javascript, this is not allowed.

You should change the property assignement that has hyphen ( `btn.style.transition-duration = "0.4s";` for example) to use [CamelCase](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style)
 instead.

```
btn.style.transitionDuration = "0.4s";
```

This might fix one of your problems. There might be more, but we can't be sure until you tell us if there is any error in the JS console and what they are.